# Very easy to fix mistake in PHP (classes)

Tags: php, class, function

I just started out working with classes, but my script just stops when I execute the page containing the class. Also, the code and functions itself are not complete at all, just some basic code added to some.

```
class doVersus
{
        private var $p1health;
        private var $p2health;
        private var $dmg;
        public var $longlog;
        function __construct($hp1m, $hp1c, $hp2m, $hp2c, $stg, $prev_log, $hp2n)
        {

                if($stg==0)
                {
                        $longlog = "The battle has begun..<br>".$_GET['user'];
                        //startBattle($hp1m, $hp1c, $hp2m, $hp2c, $stg, $prev_log, $hp2n);
                        echo $longlog;
                }else{
                        $longlog = $longlog."TURN: ".$stg."<br>";
                        //startBattle($hp1m, $hp1c, $hp2m, $hp2c, $stg, $prev_log, $hp2n);
                        echo $longLog;

        }

        private function startBattle($hp1m, $hp1c, $hp2m, $hp2c, $stg, $prev_log, $hp2n)
        {
                if($hp1c<0 || $hp2c<0)
                {
                        $longlog = $longlog."The battle has ended!<br>"
                        stopBattle($hp1c, $hp2c);
                }else{
                        echo $longlog;
                }
        }
        private function doDmg($a)
        {
                $longlog = $longlog." strikes ".$hp2n." with ".$dmg." normal damage";
        }
        private function stopBattle($a, $b)
        {
                echo $longlog." Battle has ended.";
        }
}
```

Comment: PHP has error messages. In case of an error, get it first.

Answer (score 3):

A `}` is missing in your constructor (`__construct`), at the end.

Comment: Indeed, looks like the `else{` wasn't closed.

Comment: Fixed that, still gives an HTTP-500 error code :(

Comment: I am not sure what `$longlog` var is supposed to contain, but you have to use `$this->longlong` to reference class variable instead of local variable. In `doDmg()` and `stopBattle()`, `$longlog` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

looks like `else` of the constructor is not closed

Answer (score 1):

You didn't closed the `else` statement in the constructor.

Then, in PHP5, you don't need to declare variables by writing `var` in your declarations.